# PDF files not showing in correct order in Select Dropdown

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, asp.net-core-mvc, ubuntu-22.04

I moved my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC Web application from IIS to Ubuntu 22.04 using Apache2 as the webserver.
The only issue I have is the select dropdown is not showing the pdf name files in order after moving the web app to Ubuntu. When using localhost in visual studio files show in order and IIS in Windows on a live server.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Is it an Ubuntu issue. Below is the method to add the files to the select dropdown.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```cs
public static UserFile GetPdfFiles(UserFile userFile, string webRootPath, string fileDirectoryPath)
{
    string fullPath = $"{webRootPath}{fileDirectoryPath}";
    int nId = 1;

    userFile.Files = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (string pdfPath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(fullPath, "*.pdf"))
    {
        userFile.Files.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = Path.GetFileName(pdfPath),
            Value = nId.ToString(),
        });

        nId++;
    }

    int listCount = userFile.Files.Count - 1;
    userFile.Name = userFile.Files[listCount].Text;
    userFile.Path = fileDirectoryPath.Replace('\\', '/');

    return userFile;        
}
```

**Ubuntu**

[image]

**Windows/locahost**

[image]

Comment: where are you specifying the order?  You need to specify it some place if you want it a certain way.

Comment: I'm not specify the order anywhere in my code. I have a file manager where I upload the documents which sorts the files by filename

Comment: It is reasonable to think that `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` probably makes an OS-level call.  So it is also reasonable to think that the behavior on one OS might be slightly different from another OS.  A wild guess is that when you were on IIS (windows OS) you were getting some type of default sort order on FileName whereas on Ubuntu you might be seeing a different default sort order or no sort order.  If you make it explicit in your code that will probably resolve the problem: in other words it should give you code that works for both environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` method returns items on the Windows and on the Ubuntu in a different order. In the Windows files already sorted by ascendance, but seems like on the Ubuntu files returned in order they was created (not sorted).

Therefore if want to show files in specific order it is necessary to sort them. For example, to sort by ascendance:

```cs
foreach (string pdfPath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(fullPath, "*.pdf").Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).OrderBy(o => o))
{
    userFile.Files.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = pdfPath,
        Value = nId.ToString(),
    });

    nId++;
}
```